# What does "salted peanut" mean?

Tags: meaning

I tried to search for it meaning, but I couldn't find it.

This is the sentence,

> Withdrawal of U.S. troops will become like salted peanuts to the American public; the more U.S. troops come home, the more will be demanded.

Does it mean like addicting?

Comment: It's been used metaphorically in your sentence to mean something that's *addictive and in demand*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means like addicting. Peanuts are popular in the US, and the metaphor means that if you get one, you will want another, and another, and another...